# Behat Testing website with Java Applets

Tags: java, selenium, applet, behat

I would like to send some data from Javascript to Java applet during test process. However, when Selenium starts Firefox window, in place of Java applet I see "Active Java".

Selenium launches Firefox as `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -foreground`

Launching browser same way, with same user and setting "Allow and Remember" has no impact on Firefox session launched by Selenium.

Behat session configuration is as follows:

```
selenium2:
    browser: firefox
    wd_host: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'
    capabilities: { "browserName": "firefox", "browser": "firefox"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had to set-up profile using firefox (`firefox -p`).
Then the problems was solved by simply archiving profile with `cd ~/.mozila/firefox/profilefolder && zip -r profile.zip *` and configuring behat as follows:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            sessions:
                firefox:
                    selenium2:
                        browser: firefox
                        wd_host: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'
                        capabilities: { "browserName": "firefox", "browser": "firefox", "firefox": {"profile": "features/bootstrap/profile.zip"}}
```